# Converting the 3.3V PWM signal to 5V PWM signal

Tags: arduino-nano, esp32

I am using ESP32....the max Pwm signal of it is 3.3V...And I have to control two motors speed by TB6612FNG motor driver...when i was using Arduino.. The arduino can send max 5V Pwm signal to the motor drivers PWM pin.. And the motor runs at the exact speed...but now i have to use ESP32..which sends 3.3V and the motors slow down..

So what should I do to convert the ESP32's PWM signal to 5v and according If i change the PWM value at the program..the output will also change similarly as Arduino??
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [TB6612FNG](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14451) datasheet i read

> Logic supply voltage (VCC) can be in the range of 2.7--5.5VDC

So, if you supply 3.3V to VCC all should be ok, if the motors themselves get enough power (via VM)